# Separate thread background service with communication with activity in Android application

Tags: android, multithreading, broadcastreceiver, android-service, android-broadcast

I'm an experienced Web-developer, but I'm very new to the Android SDK and Java. I have a **conceptual** question regarding background operations and multithreading in Android application.

I'm going to develop an app which will has a constantly-working background service (it will communicate with remote server over HTTP). Also, I'm going to have an activity that should display some status of the service, e.g. current operation and state.

So the idea is the following:

1. When WIFI connects, the service should start, when WIFI disconnects, the service should stop. In other words, it should only work when there is an active wireless connection. I think I will need to implement an event handler of some kind to do so.
2. The service should be running in a separate thread in order not to block the UI thread.
3. Activity should be able to connect to the service and receive the status from it dynamically.

Of course, I'm not looking for a complete solution, just for some hints from an experienced professionals of what API components should I use.

Particularly, I'm interested in a safe way to run service in a separate thread and in the same time communicate with the activity. Any suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Comment: google for android bound services

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your question point-wise:

**1.** Create a custom `BroadcastReceiver` that intercepts the `WIFI_STATE_CHANGED` broadcast. Start the HTTP requests in its `onReceive()` method in a separate `Service` when connectivity is available.

**2.** To perform HTTP requests, you can use either an `IntentService` **OR** a `Service` with `AsyncTask`s.

**3.** Use a [***bound*** `Service`](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html). This is actually not the *best* solution for this type of problem, but its a good starting point and can be refined later on.

Comment: Answer is perfectly fine, but I would advise against a bound service, if the service should ever run while the activity is not. Otherwise you'll end up with a service that is bound _and_ started with `startService`. Been there, done that. I regret it now. Unless you're communicating _a lot_ of data between the `Activity` and the `Service`, just use `startService()` and a broadcast receiver.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I think I will just start developing a prototype, based on your recommendations. However, could you please explain why bound service is not the best candidate for the job? What exactly is the problem with such approach?

Comment: @ci_ whats wrong with bound local service actually? it is much better than starting a service and passing data via extras, broadcast receivers etc...

Comment: @ci_:  agreed. but they also need a way to communicate with the `Activity`. Without a bound `Service`, that becomes tricky very fast. Since the OP is an experienced programmer coming from another domain, I think they should start with something that would simplify their work, and then gradually move towards the perfect solution, bit by bit.

Comment: @pskink nothing is wrong with a bound service, as long as you use it like it is intended to be used, otherwise things will get messy http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html "A bound service typically lives only while it serves another application component and does not run in the background indefinitely."

Comment: @ci_ the keyword here is "typically", if you start the service before binding all above doesnt apply

Comment: @pskink you can do a lot of things, I've done this myself, I wouldn't do it again. Do what you like.

Comment: @ci_ yeah, fortunately google thinks otherwise and uses bound services quite often